# How to maintain minimized windows with VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using VSC it is convenient to have several windows.

In my workflow I have a few such windows opened and a few minimized at a given moment. And this is all good.

Here is what gets in my way and I would like to know how to handle.

I wish to keep my VSC windows opened or minimized according to my taste of the moment.

But when I shut down my Mac, then after booting, all the VSC windows are opened, instead of keeping their original state (before the shutdown or reboot). How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is "iconizing"? Is that a Mac-specific thing? You might want to add the [tag:macos] tag. Or if this behaviour isn't specific to VSC, it'd probably be better ask on [apple.se] instead.

Comment: Sorry instead of "iconized" I should have written "minimized". Though I have only used VSC on a Mac, I do not think my question is specific to Mac.